# How to replace first occurrence of a pattern

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I’m trying to clean up some city names in a hive table using regexp_replace function.

For example I’d like to change the city name “St Stephens” with “Saint Stephens” and “S Salt Lake City” with “South Salt Lake City”.

I’m trying `regexp_replace(city,’St ‘,’Saint’)` but with the case of “St Stephens” I end up with “Saint Saintephens”

Similarly when trying to replace the Leading S of “S Salt Lake City” I end up with “South Southalt Lake City”.

Comment: You're probably better off restricting it to word boundaries. Try looking at the \b word boundary regex character.

Comment: First you need to split column using'St' and make it as column and then replace with 'Saint' . Then Concat it as single column

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the beginning of the string anchor `^` and do not forget to include space also. This will replace `St` (St and one space) only in the beginning of the string:

```
regexp_replace(city,'^St ','Saint ')
```

For two replacements like in your question the easy way is to apply `regexp_replace` twice:

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(city,'^St ','Saint '),'^S ','South ')
```